# How to remove rows based on another Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I've been working with pandas for a while but I haven't figured out how to achieve the following result.

DF A consists of records that contain active and inactive LOB. I want to remove the inactive LOBs. But the inactive LOBs differ between states.

DF B consists of States as columns and the inactive LOBs in the resulting columns.

So, I want a resulting DF which does not contain any inactive LOBs.

ex: an LOB 78 inactive in OH could be active in MI.
Reasoning:

In the DF a: you can see a record with state OH, and LOB 78. I do not want this record in the DF C because it is considered inactive due to 78 existing in the column OH in DF b.

In DF a: you can see a record with state MI, and LOB 78. I want the record in my DF C because there is no 78 in the column MI in DF b

DF A has 500k records in it. Time to run isn't an issue, but it would be great if it was less than 5 minutes.

(I read DF B from a list of `dict : [{state: [list of inactive lob]}]` )

Sample DF A:

```
Name, state, LOB, ID
a   , OH   , 66 , 7979
aa  , OH   , 78 , 12341
bas , OH   , 67 , 13434
basd, VT   , 99 , 1241234
badf, MI   , 77 , 12341234
bbdf, MI   , 78 , 12341234
caff, VT   , 66 , 2134
cdse, AZ   , 01 , 232
```

sample DF B:

```
    OH  ,  VT  ,  MI
    66  ,  99  ,  77
    78  ,  23
```

I want a DF C:

```
Name, state, LOB, ID
bas , OH   , 67 , 13434
bbdf, MI   , 78 , 12341234
caff, VT   , 66 , 2134
cdse, AZ   , 01 , 232
```

Comment: Could you better explain? `an LOB 78 inactive in OH could be active in M` doesn't seem to clear to me

Comment: In the DF a: you can see a record with state OH, and LOB 78. I do not want this record in the resulting DF because it is considered inactive due to 78 existing in the column OH in DF b.
In DF a: I want the record with state MI and LOB 78 in my resulting DF because there is no 78 in the column MI in DF b.

Comment: @yatu I updated the question to be more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can do an anti left join by first melting `dfb`

```
dfc= pd.merge(
    dfa,
    pd.melt(dfb, var_name="state", value_name="LOB"),
    on=["state", "LOB"],
    how="left",
    indicator=True,
).query('_merge != "both"').drop("_merge", axis=1)
```

---

```
print(dfc)

   Name state  LOB        ID
2  bas     OH   67     13434
5  bbdf    MI   78  12341234
6  caff    VT   66      2134
7  cdse    AZ    1       232
```

Comment: This worked great. For some reason it changed the dtype of state to object (after melt). So, I had to melt before the merge call and change the dtype there. But, it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Ah maybe you need to replace the blank space to nan so it reads as int in any case glad to help @Harsha

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi-index to achieve this as follows:

First, index A using both `state` and `LOB`:

```
A2 = A.set_index(['state', 'LOB'])
```

Then remove the rows you don't want in A:

```
to_remove = sum([[(list(d.keys())[0], vi) for vi in list(d.values())[0]] for d in B], [])  # If we use the list dictionaries without converting it to DataFrame
C = A2.loc[list(set(A2.index) - set(to_remove))]
```

After this `C` will contain only the rows you want. Let me know if it helps.